# Laravel authentication with new model & guard fails: Undefined index: model

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to authenticate my Laravel application (5.8) with an additional model & guard. The problem, I receive a "Undefined index: model" error during the following login approach. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong? I've used this integration in an 5.7 Version of Laravel and it worked there without any problems.

```
 auth()->guard('partner')->login($partner);
```

[image]

**CodeSnippets:**

*Partner Model* (additional Settings)

```
class Partner extends Authenticatable  {

protected $guard = 'partner';

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'uuid';
    }

}
```

*Guards* (config.auth.php)

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'partner' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'partners',
        ],
],
```

*Providers* (config.auth.php)

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'partners' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'table' => \App\Models\Partner::class,
    ],
],
```

*Middleware Gorup* (kernel.php)

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [

        'partner' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            //\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

];
```

RouteServiceProvider

```
  protected function mapPartnerRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('partner')
            ->middleware(['partner'])
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/partner.php'));

    }
```

**Application frames Error**

[image]

Comment: Maybe ApplicationFrames when debugging can be of  more help

Comment: Thanks, I've added the Application frames Errors.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you miss to configure a model in your `partners` auth provider, i.e.:

```
'partners' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    //'table' => \App\Models\Partner::class,
    'model' => \App\Models\Partner::class,
],
```